# Pdf viewer library with page curl in android

Tags: android, pdf, view

I want to know that is there any library for reading pdf in your application which contains,

1. show only one page at a time
2. have page curl effect or swipe for the next page
3. zoom in and zoom our for the current page

Comment: you need to convert your pdf pages to images and you add curl effect and zoom to that image

Comment: refer this link how to convert pdf to image http://sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/files/

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Radee](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/forum/Application-adopting-PDFViewer-SDK/3-radaee-pdf-reader) pdf reader sdk it supports many functionality. Also, you can check using their pdf reader on [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=radaee.pdf)

Comment: Is it free?! for open source/free projects?!

Comment: its a paid library have a look http://www.radaeepdf.com/ecommerce/technical-specification